# Changing value of variables in child component based on a v-select in the parent component (Vuetify)

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am trying to change (true/false) values in my child component by selecting some values in the parent component. I have a v-select in the parent component and by selecting a value in that v-select it should change the value in child from true to false and vice-versa. So basically if I select "rPanel" in parent component. the Tab "rPanel" should showup in child component. I tried something myself but my code doesn't work. What's the best way to do it?

Here is my code:

This is the parent component called "SubrackEdit":

```
<template>
<div>
.
.
 <app-tabs class="tabs"
          :rPanel="value.rPanel"
          :threeUExpansion="value.threeUExpansion"
          :threeUCompact="value.threeUCompact"
          :threeU="value.threeU"
          :sixU="value.sixU"
                      ></app-tabs>

<v-select
      v-model="value"
      :items="items"
      chips
      background-color="blue"
      color="blue"
      label="Select Subracks to be Configured:"
      multiple
      outline
    ></v-select>
.
.
</div>
</template>

<script>
.
.
value: ['rPanel', 'threeU', 'sixU', 'threeUCompact', 
'threeUExpansion'],
      items: [
        "rPanel",
        "threeU",
        "sixU",
        "threeUCompact",
        "threeUExpansion"
      ]
    }
.
.
</script>
```

This is the child component called "Tabs":

```
<template>
<div >
  .
  .
    <v-tabs centered
            grow
            icons-and-text
            v-model="active"
            color="blue darken-3"
            dark
            slider-color="white"
    >
      <v-tab v-if="sixU" href="#tab-1">
        6U Subrack
        <v-icon>indeterminate_check_box</v-icon>
      </v-tab>

      <v-tab v-if="threeU" href="#tab-2">
        3U Interface
        <v-icon>indeterminate_check_box</v-icon>
      </v-tab>

      <v-tab v-if="threeUCompact" href="#tab-3">
        3U Compact
        <v-icon>indeterminate_check_box</v-icon>
      </v-tab>

      <v-tab v-if="threeUExpansion" href="#tab-4">
        3U Expansion
        <v-icon>indeterminate_check_box</v-icon>
      </v-tab>

      <v-tab v-if="rPanel" href="#tab-5">
        Relay Panel
        <v-icon>indeterminate_check_box</v-icon>
      </v-tab>
    </v-tabs>
.
.
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props:["rPanel", "threeU", "sixU", "threeUCompact", 
"threeUExpansion"], 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `props` to pass data from parent to child and `$emit` event to emit updated data from child to parent component:

in parent component you have:

```
  <child :value="val" @update="updateVal" />
```

in data object and methods :

```
   data(){
      return{
            val:false
         }
       },
    methods:{
          updateVal(v){//<--- v is the value that's emitted from child component
               this.val=v;
            }
        }
```

and in child component :

```
   this.$emit("update", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I find this is a better approach if you're having a dynamic attribute to update

**Parent**

```
<BaseSelect v-model.trim="item" :items="items"/>

data() {
  return {
    item: "Hello",
    items: ['Hello', 'Hi']
  }
}
```

then **Child** component

```
<v-select :value="value" :items="items" solo @input="updatevalue"></v-select>

export default {
  name: 'BaseSelect',
  props: {
    value: { type: String },
    items: { type: Array, required: true }
  },
  methods: {
    updateValue(value) {
     this.$emit('input', value);
    }
  }
}
```

In this case, you don't need to define a method in Parent component just to change the value